# List of matrices in function environment

Tags: r, function, global-variables, assign

i have a function that involves creating a list of matrices.  i use `assign()` to name the matrices in that list.  this works well in the global environment.  however, if i use this technique within a function environment, i get an `object not found` error.  i have a work around which is to use  `envir = .GlobalEnv` as an argument in the `assign()`, however, i do not think this is the best solution (i would rather not fill up my global environment with these variables).  is there a better way?  here is a sample code:

```
my_function <- function(x){
my_list <- c()
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  assign(paste("matrix", i, sep="_"), matrix(data = NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 4), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
my_list <- lapply(paste("matrix", 1:length(x), sep="_"), get)
}
```

again, if i get rid of the `envir = .GlobalEnv` argument in the above, i get an `object not found` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not a good way of designing the solution. You should append your matrices into a list.

Try something along the lines of

```
my_function <- function(x) {
    mylist <- vector("list", length(x))

    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
        mylist[[i]] <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 4)
    }

    return(mylist)
}

> my_function(1:3)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: this solution results in the following warning message:  `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Comment: @VictorMaxwell see now. I've edited the way list is being subsetted.

Comment: yes, this works.  i have marked this as the answer. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is this something working for you?

```
my_list     <- list()
my_function <- function(x){
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
        my_list[[paste("matrix", i, sep="_")]] <<- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 4)
    }
}
```

call function:

```
my_function(1:3)
```

side note:

So the idea is to declare my_list as an empty list in the global envir. And then push each element into it. Please note the `<<-` as you want to add from fun-envir into the global-envir.